# How to only change text between specific times

Tags: javascript

My name is Bram and I am building a website for my company.

I came up with the idea that instead of showing welcome, the message should change according to the part of the day, like good morning, good afternoon and so on.

Now I run into some problems, which unfortunately I cannot solve by myself. I have searched a lot for a solution, but no tutorial or forum seems to help.

I want the following text to appear between the times as shown below:
-Goodnight from 0.00 to 6.00
-Good morning from 6.00 to 12.00
-Good afternoon from 12.00 to 18.00
-Good evening from 18.00 to 0.00

[image]

I hope you guys can help me out with some nice suggestions.

Thanks in advance anyways!

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use the `getHours()` method. For more info go here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp

```js
const date = new Date();
let hour = date.getHours();

if(hour > 5 && hour <= 12) console.log('good morning!') 
else if(hour > 12 && hour <= 17) console.log('good afternoon!') 
else if(hour > 17 && hour <= 21) console.log('good evening!') 
else if(hour > 21 && hour <= 5) console.log('good night!')
```